# Gson - proper ways to check for node/element existance

Tags: java, android, json, parsing, gson

When I have a `JsonObject`, in order to retrieve a specified element member from it, there would be a couple of methods, for instance, `get()` and other `getAsXXX()`:

```
JsonPrimitive childNode1 = parent.getAsJsonPrimitive("key1);
JsonArray childNode2 = parent.getAsJsonArray("key2);
JsonElement childNode3 = parent.get("key3);
```

My question is that, is `isJsonNull()` the way to check if an element exists? I got a bit confused by Json's documentation.

Comment: for java there are various Json library over internet. So which library are you using. Give the link to the JSON library and documentation

Comment: @Thuy Trinh Check out my answer.

Comment: @Veer Thanks for pointing out. Just changed into Gson.

Answer (score 7):

You can use JsonObject.has() in order to determine if an element exists.

See [code definition](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/ee61e3f020351f0498dd3ff8f8386b96454a4dfe/gson/src/main/java/com/google/gson/JsonObject.java#L173).